# HTML Table with with w3css accordion button

Tags: html, css, html-table, accordion

I am trying to create an html table using the w3css accordion button, what I have so far...

codepen.io/thehellwithjfiddler/pen/bZyWZN

When I click on a header (any header), the background of such header doesn't work for the entire row (the row changed width after the click, to show the data, but the header didn't..).

Please help

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding what you're saying.. but your td's have a max-width: set to 120px so they are not expanding.

Comment: what do you mean by entire row? Do you want ,your accordion body color same as your header color?

Comment: Hi Nalin, i want the header color to "grab" the entire header row (same row header is in) when the table rows expand after click. I have an image in case you had trouble opening the code in codepen.  http://i.imgur.com/AZUWoXM.jpg

Answer (score 0):

As per your last comment, If you are looking for a scroll in the container or body of the accordian try this

```
.w3-show-block, .w3-show {
    display: block!important;    
    overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Ty Nalin for your answer. I would like to point out that I am trying (sadly) to build an html table that is: 
a) Scrollable horizontaly. 
b) Has a toggle header that shows or hides following rows.
c)Looks neat and tidy.
I tried your solution, but look what happens to the headers when you scroll..
Thank you.

Comment: lol, no, i actually want it like it is but without the headache

Comment: Hope this will be helpfull now !!@user2570938

Comment: You sir are a god, that is 100% exactly what i wanted. Thank you very much.

Comment: woop !! woop!! please mark this as a answer if it helps!! @user2570938